# Align divisions inside a container to center for first row but to left when divisions shift to next row

Tags: html, css

I am using divisions to be printed inside a for loop.

Like

```
  <?php
 for($ab=0; $ab<$total_sheets ;$ab++)
  {

 ?>
<div id="books" class="one-column">

    //printing some data here....
</div>
<?php
} 
?>
```

I want in this that for first 4 divisions they align to center and after that when divisions dont fit in same row ...they shift to next line where they float to left.

Float centre for first row and then float left for other rows.

CSS I am using for id books and its container is as follows:

```
    #container {max-width:80%;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;} 
    #container #books {display: inline-block; float:none;vertical-align:top;}
```

But This aligns all the divisions to center of container even when divisions exceeds single row. But I want that as the divisions passes to second row , they automatically shift to left whereas first row remain centerally aligned.

Please help me out with this. How can achieve this design?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So are you always going to have more than 4 columns? Oh, and by the way that code is going to create multiple divs with the id of books. ids are unique, meaning you can't have more than one element with the same id on the same page. Well you can, but you shouldn't (ever).

Comment: The reason you can't have multiple IDs of the same value is because it's W3C invalid HTML, and also breaks Javascript.

Aside from that, @user3414076 is there any requirement for a CSS only method, or can you add classes programmatically through php for when say `if ($ab >= 4)`?

Comment: No..I am not having more than four columns everytime. When I will be having more than four I want them to float left. And I want these divs to be of same id because the data I am displaying in them is being fetched from database. So I can have any number of divs ranging from one to many. Naming everyone different isnt possible. @rick Calder

Comment: @akurn I dont know much about classes in php. But I can do like if($ab>=4), I can use some different css aligining elements to left else can make them center aligned. Will that be ok?

Comment: @user3414076 not being able to use a different id because of data doesn't make sense. Can't you just use a class "books" and update your CSS? Unless you're using JS or AJAX to insert the data using those IDs, but then that's a whole different issue, because how is that even working with multiple same IDs?

Comment: You need to do something to increment those id's trust me you don't want to be writing invalid HTML like that and if you ever intend on applying javascript to one, or all, of those divs it won't work with identical ID's.

Comment: I see a potential issue for your 2nd row if you use floats.  Unless the `<div id="book">` all have the same height, you may sometimes get a row with less than 4 panels is one of the panel is slightly taller than its adjacent siblings. Please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 <?php
 for($ab=0; $ab<$total_sheets ;$ab++)
  {

 ?>
<div id="book<?php echo $ab;?>" class="books one-column<?php if ($ab >= 4) { echo " align-left"; } ?>">

    //printing some data here....
</div>
<?php
} 
?>
```

Then update your CSS:

```
#container {max-width:80%;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;} 
#container .books {display: inline-block; float:none;vertical-align:top;}
#container .align-left {float: left;}
```

Comment: It displays all the divs vertically stretched to full length of container.

Comment: Sorry, I was more demonstrating the concept rather than fixing the actual problem. Do you have a jsfiddle.net example? (of the rendered HTML) Should be easier to solve that way

Comment: I managed for JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ambhar/Sg9ha/1/ Here I want the bottom div to go left automatically.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. So you want it to happen automatically if the items are too wide for the container? That might not actually be possible without an elaborate Javascript example. BUT if you can limit it to the first `N` number of items, you can have a look at this for styles: http://jsfiddle.net/Sg9ha/2/. Then use the PHP logic I wrote above to add the `bookmarkboxleft` class.

Comment: Yes..you got my requirement now.